# Any good open-source file recovery software for Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery

Is there any good (i.e., robust, effective, thorough, etc.) open-source file recovery software for Windows X out there? All I get after a google search is a bunch of paid software, of which probably 90% are scams or lie about being free up until the moment when you click "Recover"! I'm wondering, since the open-source community has projects for all kinds of utilities, and doing a deep disk scan through unallocated space doesn't seem that complex of a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is powerful free data recovery software. It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software: certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will mark your answer as correct as it answers my question completely. A separate sub-question would be if it is possible to recover the file names of lost files?

Comment: If the goal is solely to recover data, PhotoRec from the same creators is easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Piriform Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download) is 100% free. Just you won't get support.
Please understand that such a file recovery is very unlikely to be successful, as it is based on the fact that sectors containing lost data have not already been overwritten, just marked for deletion. And such thing is very difficult in Ms Windows as the system is always looking for the disk having some MS weirdness to write to on it.